# how to ask an app to be rated with flutter?

Tags: flutter

Maybe someone has used this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app to ask users to rate the app. I wonder if the rating that is marked using that plugin can be passed to the respective store (app store and play store), and how to test this functionality or can it only be done once the app is published?

Or what other plugin could I use to ask the user to rate my app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be done once the app is published. if your app is in testing phase. you can add different package name like google chrome for android and safari for ios like this.
You can also Use this as the example as well.   `static const playStoreId = 'com.packageName.packageName'; static const appstoreId = 'com.packageName.packageName';`

Example : https://github.com/Skyost/RateMyApp/tree/master/example/lib

To Implement the rate my app Here is the example you only have to add in
https://github.com/Skyost/RateMyApp/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart.

````
rateMyApp: RateMyApp(
          googlePlayIdentifier: playStoreId,
          appStoreIdentifier: appstoreId,
          minDays: 0,
          minLaunches: 2,
          // remindDays: 1,
          // remindLaunches: 1,
        )```
````

Comment: Then the number of stars is automatically placed. Is that going to be registered in the respective store? I did not understand your example very well.

Comment: I already have the application published, but I want to add the functionality for users to rate it, can that be tested in local or test mode?

Comment: @EzequielJaramillo added the example.

Comment: Thanks, my project is not made with the Android Embedding V2 version, and I have some add-ons that don't use that version, and I can't remove them from the project, can that add-on still be used?